# Centered, inline texts re-positions upon fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm in a little pickle here.  I tried to create a centered, inline text with two different sentences fading in at different speed using the callback *fadein* function with JQuery.  The problem is that the animation is not what I quite wanted: the first word appears in the center first then as the second word appears, it pushes the first word to the left.

Is there a way I can have those texts in a fixed, centered position?  I've tried applying *relative*, *absolute* to each individual texts and shifted the position to the left using css, but it messes up the responsiveness of the design.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $("#2").fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <p id="1" style="display:none;">Hello.</p>
  <p id="2" style="display:none;">World.</p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksfnm3n8/32/)

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: can you provide a working snippet?

Comment: Yes, apologies.  I just updated the link of the JSFiddle right now.

Comment: Have you tried setting the dimensions of the div to a fixed size? You may be hitting the text not actually being there. Alternatively, you could place the text with the same color as the background and fade in its color.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `opacity` or `visibility` instead, as those will keep the elements' layout on the page, and just visually hide/show them. If you want to fade `opacity`, use `$.fadeTo()` instead of `$.fadeIn()` - https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#1").fadeTo('fast',1,function() {
     $("#2").fadeTo('slow',1);
   });
 });
```

```css
#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <p id="1">Hello.</p>
  <p id="2">World.</p>
</div>
```

You can also do this with CSS. Here I'm adding a class that enables `opacity: 1`, and you can control the timing in the CSS transition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#1").on('transitionend',function() {
     $("#2").addClass('ready');
   }).addClass('ready');
});
```

```css
#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.ready {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <p id="1">Hello.</p>
  <p id="2">World.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @John you bet :)